# Avoid sending zero values to InfluxDB

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm using Spring Boot Actuator + Micrometer to send values to micrometer, so i have the following maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-influx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

So, i have a method that start timer and stop timer sample (micrometer):

```
public Timer.Sample starTimer() {
        return Timer.start(registry);
    }

    public void stopTimer(Class clazz, Timer.Sample sample) {
        sample.stop(registry.timer("timer-dev", Arrays.asList(Tag.of("modulo", modulo), Tag.of("class", clazz.getName()))));
    }
```

So, this works very well. InfluxDB receive value sent from Spring Boot Application and show in Grafana.

**The problem:** After sending "timer-dev" first time to influx, spring boot keeping sending values "0" continually, i would like avoid spring boot sending zero values, it should send only when timer-dev greater then zero. The "timer-dev" should be sent only when this method is called not everytime.

Any tips  ?